# AOSP build image compilation error android 7

Tags: android, linux

I am trying to build android 7 image in a server from linux, everything is all right with the commands ". build/envsetup" and "lunch" and when I type "make -j8"

```
PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=REL
PLATFORM_VERSION=7.1.2
TARGET_PRODUCT=aosp_bullhead
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=userdebug
TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release
TARGET_BUILD_APPS=
TARGET_ARCH=arm64
TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=armv8-a
TARGET_CPU_VARIANT=cortex-a53
TARGET_2ND_ARCH=arm
TARGET_2ND_ARCH_VARIANT=armv7-a-neon
TARGET_2ND_CPU_VARIANT=cortex-a53.a57
HOST_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_2ND_ARCH=x86
HOST_OS=linux
HOST_OS_EXTRA=Linux-4.15.0-42-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-18.04-bionic
HOST_CROSS_OS=windows
HOST_CROSS_ARCH=x86
HOST_CROSS_2ND_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release
BUILD_ID=N2G47Z
OUT_DIR=out
============================================
Running kati to generate build-aosp_bullhead-dist.ninja...
out/build-aosp_bullhead-dist.ninja is missing, regenerating...
============================================
PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=REL
PLATFORM_VERSION=7.1.2
TARGET_PRODUCT=aosp_bullhead
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=userdebug
TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release
TARGET_BUILD_APPS=
TARGET_ARCH=arm64
TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=armv8-a
TARGET_CPU_VARIANT=cortex-a53
TARGET_2ND_ARCH=arm
TARGET_2ND_ARCH_VARIANT=armv7-a-neon
TARGET_2ND_CPU_VARIANT=cortex-a53.a57
HOST_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_2ND_ARCH=x86
HOST_OS=linux
HOST_OS_EXTRA=Linux-4.15.0-42-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-18.04-bionic
HOST_CROSS_OS=windows
HOST_CROSS_ARCH=x86
HOST_CROSS_2ND_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release
BUILD_ID=N2G47Z
OUT_DIR=out
============================================
Checking build tools versions...
************************************************************
You asked for an OpenJDK based build but your version is
java version "1.8.0_191" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_191-b12) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.191-b12, mixed mode).
************************************************************
build/core/main.mk:231: *** stop.
build/core/ninja.mk:163: recipe for target 'out/build-aosp_bullhead-dist.ninja' failed
make: *** [out/build-aosp_bullhead-dist.ninja] Error 1

#### make failed to build some targets (1 seconds) ####
```

but I already followed the steps in android web page and downloaded and installed Openjdk 8 to build the images

```
java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_191"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_191-8u191-b12-0ubuntu0.18.04.1-b12)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.191-b12, mixed mode)
```

Ideas please? :c

Comment: what is your Linux version? ubuntu 14.04 is recommended

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug per:  https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8213088?attachmentViewMode=list   According to that list, it's due to the upgrade to that version of java!